# How do I resolve the error " 'Add' function is not callable" in this code using scipy library?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, typeerror, sympy

```
from sympy import *
from scipy.optimize import *
from numpy import *
import math
x=symbols("x)")
eqn1=20+3*(29.4*(1-(2.71)**(-x/3))-9.8*x)
print(fsolve(eqn1,[0,10]))
```

This shows a

> Type Error: " 'Add' function is not callable" in line 7

Comment: Don't use multiple '*' imports.  And don't use sympy expresions with numpy and scipy (unless you understand both). And lest I forget - **show the full error with traceback**

Comment: In sympy you would use `from sympy import symbols, Eq, nsolve` and `nsolve(Eq(eqn1,0), 10)`.

Answer (score 2):

From [scipy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html) the way you define your equation is like a python function and then use it in fsolve :

```
from scipy.optimize import *

def eqn1(x):
    return [20 + 3 * (29.4 * (1 - (2.71) ** (-x[0] / 3)) - 9.8 * x[0])]

print(fsolve(eqn1, [10]))
```

output:

```
>>>
[2.26874667]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this because I think you need better debugging skills, starting with paying actual attention to the full error message. And also pay attention to the function documentation.

Your code, with a couple of added prints:

```
136:~/mypy$ python3 stack70732461.py 
-29.4*x) + 108.2 - 88.2/2.71**(x)/3)
<class 'sympy.core.add.Add'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stack70732461.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(fsolve(eqn1,[0,10]))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 160, in fsolve
    res = _root_hybr(func, x0, args, jac=fprime, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 226, in _root_hybr
    shape, dtype = _check_func('fsolve', 'func', func, x0, args, n, (n,))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 24, in _check_func
    res = atleast_1d(thefunc(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args)))
TypeError: 'Add' object is not callable
```

`eqn1` is a `sympy.add.Add` object.

You pulled `fsolve` from `scipy` (all those '*' imports can be confusing).  That function, down a couple layers ends up trying to do:

```
thefunc(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args))
```

which given your code amounts to:

```
eqn1([0,10])
```

and error says that `eqn1` is an `Add`, not a function.  Sympy expressions are not functions.  `scipy` functions like `fsolve` expect Python functions.

```
func
callable f(x, *args)
A **function** that takes at least one (possibly vector) argument, and returns a value of the same length.
```

Others have suggested fixes, but the bottom line is you should not be mixing `sympy` and `scipy` without understanding both.  Either use `fsolve` with a proper Python function, or use a `sympy` solver with your equation.

Changing your code to

```
...
#print(fsolve(eqn1,[0,10]))

from sympy import symbols, Eq, nsolve 
print(nsolve(Eq(eqn1,0), 10))

def eqn1(x):
    return [20 + 3 * (29.4 * (1 - (2.71) ** (-x[0] / 3)) - 9.8 * x[0])]

print(fsolve(eqn1, [10]))
```

produces a

```
2.26874667256491
[2.26874667]
```